# StartCopyAsync crash after 6 hours - Azure blob copy

Tags: c#, azure

I'm writing a console app that will copy a blob from Source(using SAS Uri) to the destination.
I am fetching the blob status attributes to find the copy status while copying. The application is not writing to console(I am writing status to console after every 2 or 3 min) after 6 hours. The blob size is huge so it is taking so much time(more than 6 hours).
My console is active but not printing anything on the console after 6 hours.

Can anyone suggest how to know what is the issue with the copy?

```
                try
                    {

                    await targetBlob.StartCopyAsync(SasURI);
                    while (targetBlob.CopyState.Status == CopyStatus.Pending)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Blob Copy Pending");
                        Thread.Sleep(120000);
                        targetBlob.FetchAttributes();
                        if (targetBlob.CopyState.Status == CopyStatus.Aborted || targetBlob.CopyState.Status == CopyStatus.Failed || targetBlob.CopyState.Status == CopyStatus.Invalid)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Blob Copy Failed");
                        }
                    }

                    if (targetBlob.CopyState.Status == CopyStatus.Success)
                    {
                       Console.WriteLine("Blob Copy Success");
                        IsSucc = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Blob Copy Failed");
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Blob Copy Failed due to exception:"+ex.Message);
                }
```

Note: I kept the blob copy under try-catch.

Comment: What size are we talking about here?

Comment: If you are just moving files, have you looked at Azure Data Factory?  It can perform data migrations and be kicked off via an http call.

Comment: I dont think Console not respond after 6 hours. 

Probably application stuck somewhere? 

Could you use NLog (example) and write your logs Console and log file together. 
You will see same Console and File will be stop same line. It means your thread or application freeze!

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. The issue has been resolved by enabling the **Always on** under General configuration settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by enabling the **Always on** under General configuration settings - Azure app service.